# Sqlite - Calculation of time period

Tags: sqlite

I need to calculate the time between a 'fixed' time (usually a few days ago) and now.

Therefore I have googled me to this sql (http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

```
SELECT strftime ('%s', '1423143532') - strftime ('%s', 'now') as timediff;
```

It gives a weird result (122747310831610), and I have no idea why !? :-/

Should I use a different method of calculation, is that where the problem is? If yes, which one would give me the correct result? :)

Comment: the result you are getting is in seconds

Comment: I know, but the number seconds in the result is much lager than the seconds in the input! It doesn't make sense...

Comment: Your SQL returns NULL. Copy+paste the actual code.

Comment: It works in SQLite Manager for Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bare number is interpreted as a Julian day number:

```
> SELECT datetime('1423143532');
3891722-46318118-31 12:00:00
> SELECT datetime(2457064);
2015-02-10 12:00:00
```

To interpret a number as the number of seconds since 1970, you must use the `unixepoch` modifier:

```
> SELECT datetime(1423143532, 'unixepoch');
2015-02-05 13:38:52
> SELECT strftime ('%s', 1423143532, 'unixepoch');
1423143532
```

As you can see, passing this number through `strftime` is pointless. Just use it directly:

```
> SELECT 1423143532 - strftime('%s', 'now') as timediff;
-436916
```